# Xamarin Listview data not showing up?

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I decided that I need a custom `ListView` for all platforms which can show multiple data fields on my `ListView`. So I decided to check out the code from https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithListviewNative and modify it in my module. However my `ListView` is never showing any values / view and I have no idea why.

**HorsePage.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Begijnhoeve.Pages.HorsesPage"
         Title="Horse Overview">
</ContentPage>
```

**HorsePage.xaml.cs:**

```
var nativeListViewHorse = new NativeListViewHorse(); // CUSTOM RENDERER using a native control
        nativeListViewHorse.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        nativeListViewHorse.Items = DAHorse.DataAccess.DAHorse.GetList();
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(0, Device.OnPlatform(20, 0, 0), 0, 0),
            Children = {
                new Label {
                    XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                    Text = Device.OnPlatform("Custom UITableView+UICell","Custom ListView+Cell","Custom renderer todo")
                },
                nativeListViewHorse
            }
        };
```

**DAHorse.cs (Data Access layer):**

```
namespace DAHorse.DataAccess
{
  class DAHorse
  {
    private static object locker = new object();
    private static SQLiteConnection db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite_PCL>().GetConnection();
    public static List<Horse> GetList()
    {
        var l = new List<Horse>();

        l.Add(new Horse("HorseA", "1999"));
        l.Add(new Horse("HorseB", "2000"));
        l.Add(new Horse("HorseC", "2000"));
        Debug.WriteLine("YAPYAPYAPYAP");
        return l;
    }
  }
}
```

**NativeListViewHorse.cs (Custom list view):**

```
public class NativeListViewHorse : View
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Items", typeof(IEnumerable<Horse>), typeof(NativeListViewHorse), new List<Horse>());

    public IEnumerable<Horse> Items
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<Horse>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public event EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> ItemSelected;

    public void NotifyItemSelected(object item)
    {

        if (ItemSelected != null)
            ItemSelected(this, new SelectedItemChangedEventArgs(item));
    }

    public NativeListViewHorse()
    {
    }
}
```

When I debug the line where the `Content` is filled I will get the following data:
[image]
Why isn't anything showing up while the data is seen in the variable? Have I done something wrong or?

With kind regards,
Yenthe

Comment: There are many different samples in that link, so it's hard to know exactly which one you're trying to follow.  But your NativeListView just inherits from View, and doesn't really DO anything.  A View is just an empty canvas, you need to place other elements (labels, buttons, etc) on it.

Comment: @Jason I'm using sample D as see here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithListviewNative/WorkingWithListviewNative/D as for the View is just an empty canvas.. I can't find anything in the D sample that fills up specific labels or anything?

Comment: there are also D folders under the iOS and Android projects that contain custom platform code.  You need that too

Comment: Hmm I see.. I thought that the code from the portable would be enough. Guess this was a bad question then :s Is there a way to make this multi-platform without writing seperated code for every platform? I would love to stick with having everything in my portable project.

Comment: You can create custom LIstView cell templates without writing rendering code for each platform.  http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/listview/#custom

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'll have a look at those. If you wish to make an answer from your comments I'll be more than happy to accept this, since this really helped. Thanks!